# Open port to all interfaces

Tags: adb, ssh, usb-tethering

I have an old machine with no built-in wifi adapter. I'm using a spare android device to connect this machine to my wifi home network via usb tethering. I'd like to ssh into this machine. The machine's ip address is behind the usb-tethering subnet.

What I tried:

```
adb reverse tcp:2222 tcp:22
```

I'm able to ssh from an app running inside the android device (e.g. connectbot) into the machine. But when I try to connect from another device on the home network:

```
ssh -p2222 <android-device-ip-address>
```

I get connection refused. `nmap` reports that all ports in the android device are closed.

How can I open port `2222` to accept connections from outside the android device?